# How to change Linear model in SGDClassifier scikit learn?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, machine-learning-model

The [SGDClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) of scikit learn defines it as *"Linear classifiers (SVM, logistic regression, etc.) with SGD training."*. I understand from this that any Linear classifier can be used here. I want to know that how can we define a specific linear classifier to be used in the case of SGDClassifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific linear classifier can be defined with the loss function argument. The options are { ‘hinge’, ‘log’, ‘modified_huber’, ‘squared_hinge’, ‘perceptron’}. For example, [hinge loss is equivalent to a linear SVM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#classification) and [log loss is equivalent to Logistic Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#mathematical-formulation).